# How to get the value of input in table row and push them in array based on there name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying the push the value of the input in the array based on the no of the rows in the table. If there are two rows then there will be array of two. Below is the working code.
I am a

```js
$(document).on('focus',".datepicker", function(){
    $(this).daterangepicker();
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    // $('.datepicker').daterangepicker();

    var counter = 1;

    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        // $('input[name="event_date['+counter+']"]').daterangepicker();

        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="round" /></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" name="event_date" class="form-control datepicker" required></td>';
        cols += '<td><select class="form-control show-tick" name="judginground"><option value="BYENTRYTHENCATEGORY" selected="selected">Those specifically assigned to them. If none, those in assigned categories</option><option value="BYCATEGORY">Only those in assigned categories</option><option value="BYENTRY">Only those specifically assigned to them</option><option value="BYENTRYORCATEGORY">Those specifically assigned to them or in assigned categories</option><option value="ANY">All</option></select></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="checkbox" class="filled-in chk-col-grey" name="is_final"><label for="md_checkbox_38"></label></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger "  value="Delete"></td>';

        newRow.append(cols);
        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
        counter++;
        
    });



    $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();       
        counter -= 1
    });


});



function calculateRow(row) {
    var price = +row.find('input[name^="price"]').val();

}

function calculateGrandTotal() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $("table.order-list").find('input[name^="price"]').each(function () {
        grandTotal += +$(this).val();
    });
    $("#grandtotal").text(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
}

$("#get_all_data").on('click',function(){

     var table = $('#round_form #myTable');
    var data = [];

    table.find('tbody tr').each(function (i, el) {
        // if( i != 0){
      var $tds = $(this).find('td');
      var row = [];
      $tds.each(function (i, el){
          var selected_val = $("input[name=judginground]").val();
        // row.push($(this).text());
        if($(this).text() != 'undefined'){
            row.push($(this).find("input").val());
            row.concat($(this).text());
        }
        
        // row.concat("mohammed");

        // row.concat("#");judginground
        // row.concat($("input[name=judginground]").val());
        
      });
      data.push(row);
    // }
        
  });
  console.log(data)
//   return data;
    // get all the inputs into an array.
    



})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
  <form id="round_form" >
        <table class="table table-bordered table order-list"  id="myTable" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Round#</th>
                    <th>Start Time - End Time</th>
                    <th>all</th>
                    <th>Enable Finalizing</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="text" name="round" class="form-control" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-sm-3">
                        <input type="text" name="event_date" class="form-control datepicker" required=''>
                    </td>
                    
                    <td class="col-sm-6">

                        <select class="form-control show-tick" name="judginground" >
                        <option value="BYENTRYTHENCATEGORY" selected="selected">Those specifically assigned to them. If none, those in assigned categories</option>
                            <option value="BYCATEGORY">Only those in assigned categories</option>
                            <option value="BYENTRY">Only those specifically assigned to them</option>
                            <option value="BYENTRYORCATEGORY">Those specifically assigned to them or in assigned categories</option>
                            <option value="ANY">All</option>
                        </select>
            
                    
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in chk-col-grey" checked="" name="is_final">
                        <label for="md_checkbox_38"></label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <a class="deleteRow"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block " id="addrow" value="Add New Round" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block " id="get_all_data" value="Get All Round data" />
    </form>
```

little bit close to getting the values but select functionality is giving me an issue.

I am able to get the input value but select value is giving me undefined. please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue myself. 
just by adding this line of code 
`row.push({name_vl:$(this).find("input, select").val()});`
instead of this both lines
`row.push($(this).find("input").val());
 row.concat($(this).text());`